# How to just build Android system image

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I made some small changes in framework/base, and did a "mm" under that folder. Now I don't want to run "make" on the project root because the makefile including process is very slow.

Is there a quick way to just build the system image without going through the lengthy including process?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your changes effect other applications, use `make systemimage`, otherwise use `make snod`.

Notice:`make systemimage` will check dependency during compile progress, while `make snod` will not do this check, so the former command need more time than the latter.

Comment: And `vendor` with `make vnod` according to `make help`.