# Modify a java class file in a Android system on a Virtual Machine Disk

Tags: java, android, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I would like to modify a java class file on a Android system in an existing vmdk file.

Why I want to do that is to try to fix one of the Genymotion Android system image, because a .java class file is causing an app crash. My idea is to update this class with a newer version.

I used vmware-mount to mount the .vmdk but the file system is not recognized.

I imagine that I would have to recompile the whole system? Does it sound impossible? Is there an other way?

Comment: May I kindly ask you to accept my answer, if it's meet with your expectations. Thank you very much

Comment: Of course @Karoly , I juste wanted to keep the question opened a bit more longer to see if it brought other participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this sounds like a very interesting job, but I'm sure you can do it, since every mobile manufacturer "overriding" the Android System from Google :)

I think, I said I THINK (without experience) you should use the mmm command from android build system:

> - mmm <dir1> ... - build all of the modules in the supplied directories

http://elinux.org/Android_Build_System

**additional links:**
http://rex-shen.net/android-unpackpack-factory-images/

[How to just build Android system image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023406/how-to-just-build-android-system-image)

Maybe this link can help you out:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2251719

Comment: Thank you for the links and information, it is a good introduction to the subject for me. I still have the question about the Virtual Machine Disk file format that is not recognized when mounted with vmware-mount.