# How to reset the userdata image when building Android AOSP and running it on the emulator?

Tags: android, android-source

I built AOSP `8.1.0_r60` from source, and launched it as explained at: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48310014/9

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_x86_64-eng
emulator -show-kernel
```

Then, I've installed an app with `adb install` and played around with it.

Now, I wanted to restore the system to the initial state, before I had installed the app.

By [printing the QEMU command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445464/how-to-show-which-options-are-passed-to-qemu-when-launching-the-android-emulator) and using `find` in the device, I've noticed that the app was installed inside:

```
/data
```

which seems to come from the `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2` image:

```
-drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/path/to/aosp/8.1.0_r60/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576
```

What is the best way to reset that image to it's original state, before I had installed my app?

I even tried to do a full rebuild:

```
make
```

but the app was still present afterwards.

I have learned how to clean up `/system` quickly with `make snod` at: [How to just build Android system image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023406/how-to-just-build-android-system-image) but I could not find an analogous option for the user image.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110927/how-to-mount-system-rewritable-or-read-only-rw-ro/207200#207200), I've noticed that all writable images are qcow2 overlays of the base images.

I could not find a way to restore them through the build system, which would be ideal, but since qcow2 overlays are so simple, it is reasonable to do it manually as a workaround:

```
rm system-qemu.img.qcow2
qemu-img create -b system-qemu.img -f qcow2 system-qemu.img.qcow2 1T
```

Note that `make snod` resets the only the `.img` file, not the `.img.qcow` that `-writable-system` uses.